# Need advice on how to optimize this database further

Tags: mysql

I'm about to develop a chatsystem based on PHP / MySQL. Both the database and the website will run on the same server. I'd like to be able to support 300 users online at the same time. This will obviously generate lots of queries continuesly. Therefor optimizing the database design is a must.

My skills with MySQL are average. I did my best to learn about optimizing and did everything I understood myself. Still I'm not sure if it's good enough. I'm hoping you guys can take a look at it and give advise on how to optimize it further.

Any other tips on how to reduce the serverload are welcome aswell. Just keep in mind that all messages must be saved due to local law.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bans` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `ipaddress` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `reason` text,
    `bandate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `BAN_INDEX` (`userid`,`ipaddress`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chatboxes` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `boxname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `accesslvl` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `BOX_INDEX` (`boxname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ignorelist` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `blockedusr` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `boxname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `message` text,
    `receiver` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `alert` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `msgdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sexpref` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `regdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `lastlogin` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `warnings` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `accesslvl` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `kicks` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ipaddress` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `online` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `USER_INDEX` (`username`,`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: If you downvote my question please add a comment why so I can improve it. It's impossible to learn without feedback.

Comment: Unfortunately, it often doesn't work this way. To get a perspective on the attitude of SO downvoting and what makes for a good question, take a look at this [post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) on meta stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do not know the reasons for your choices, I would suggest that for tables which store a reference to a user in the `users` table (`bans`, `ignorelist`, `messages`), you should store the users primary key `id` (create a `userid` field to store this data in each of these tables) instead of `username`. This will allow for normalized data. If the user changes his name, you don't want to go back and update all the other tables.

Also, IP addresses are not always static, so unless you are only banning a user from a particular IP address (not very effective), and presuming the user must be logged in to chat, I would suggest banning again based on `userid` so you would have your `UNIQUE KEY` on `userid`

To query for a ban which shows the username as part of the result set, you join `bans` to `users` (e.g. `SELECT bans.reason, users.username FROM bans JOIN users ON bans.userid = users.id`)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although users will not be allowed to change their usernames, there are cases where a moderator is forced to change the username. I do see the benefits of using an id reference instead of username everywhere and will implement it inmediately.

As for the ban system there will be 2 types: Account ban and IP ban. I know it's not very effective. But without client side software, it's the best availible I guess.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: While I was hoping for some more advice and feedback on my database design, you seem to be the only one that took the time to help out. Therefor I'm accepting your answer as answered. Thanks again for helping out.